# Ajax Dynamic Loaded Content Animation

Tags: ajax, animation, load

Im working on a website that will load the content with ajax depending on the tab clicked. I want to animate the loaded content and have it slide in either from the left or from the right, and have the old content slideout or fade out. I want the user to be able to add a new .html page and attach the link to that page in the nav button, and the animation applies automatically to the ajax loaded page. Does anyone know how i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do this, from manually moving the divs with javascript, or you can use a premade library with these features.

My favorite way is to use [animate.css](https://daneden.me/animate/)  Then all you have to do is in JQuery use

```
$("elementClass").addClass("animated <effect_name_class>");
```

to apply the animation to an element.